# IBM Cloud Function for App ID sign_up and forgot_password

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-appid, ibm-cloud-functions

I can generate token from cloud with following cloud function

```
const main = (params) => {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        request({
            url: credentials.oauthServerUrl + '/token',
            method: 'POST',
            auth: {
                username: credentials.clientId,
                password: credentials.secret
            },
            form: {
                grant_type: "password",
                username: params.uid,
                password: params.pwd
            }
        }, function (error, response, body) {
            resolve(response);
        })
    })
}
```

How i can use App ID sign_up and forgot_password functionality without Node.js SDK and Express server. In other words i'd like to keep my app (SPA) serverless and use cloud functions. I have tried, and read docs for a solution, but no luck so far (http 404).

Edit: function that i tried to invoke forgot password page but result is error (statusCode 400) "missing redirect"

```
const main = (params) => {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        request({
            url: credentials.oauthServerUrl + '/forgot_password',
            method: 'GET',
            form: {
                client_id: credentials.clientId,
                redirect_uri: "http://www.google.fi"
            }
        }, function (error, response, body) {
            resolve(response);
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Well i'm progressing with this. URL https://appid-oauth.eu-gb.bluemix.net/oauth/v3/xxx/cloud_directory/forgot_password?client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=www.google.fi opens an page that asks email. It works when pasted into browser. Now i have to get it working from cloud function, where it complaints "missing redirect".

Comment: https://appid-oauth.ng.bluemix.net/swagger-ui/#!/Authorization_Server_V3/get_oauth_v3_tenantId_cloud_directory_forgot_password expects the parameters in the query string. You could use `qs` instead of `form` in the `request` call

Comment: Thanks Frederick, good catch! Now it works. Then how about sign_up, that seems to not belong to API https://appid-oauth.ng.bluemix.net/swagger-ui/#!/Authorization_Server_V3/token

Comment: also why not simply redirecting to the appid URL directly. You could do this with a Cloud Functions "web action", and sending a redirect statusCode to the client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the working solution seemed to be following:

```
const request = require('request');
const credentials = {
  "version": 3,
  "clientId": "xxx",
  "secret": "xxx",
  "tenantId": "xxx",
  "oauthServerUrl": "https://appid-oauth.eu-gb.bluemix.net/oauth/v3/xxx/cloud_directory/forgot_password"
}
const main = (params) => {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        request({
            url: credentials.oauthServerUrl 
                + '?client_id=' + credentials.clientId 
                    + '&redirect_uri=http://www.my.domain'
                ,
            method: 'GET'
        }, function (error, response, body) {
            resolve(response);
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: and for sign_up there's /oauth/v3/{tenantId}/authorization with reponse_type=sign_up.

"In case response_type equals "sign_up", the LoginWidget sign up html form will be retrieved."